# Module not found for all babel runtime helpers including react-redux?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, babeljs

I have been facing this issue along with almost all other developers on the team. Some of whom have solved this by miracle on Linux and windows machine but this 100% doesn't work on Mac with version 8.x of node as well as 12.x version

I have an existing React based application and some of the components try to import some components from babel runtime but it always return the error Module Not Found :

[image]

You can see in the below screenshot that it exists in the path

[image]

My package.json looks like this

```
{
  "name": "ant",
  "version": "1.1.6",
  "private": true,
  "homepage": "",
  "dependencies": {
       "@babel/runtime": "^7.4.5",
"@sentisis/react-tags-input": "^1.0.4",
"antd": "^3.8.2",
"axios": "^0.18.0",
"chosen-js": "^1.8.7",
"classnames": "^2.2.6",
"echarts": "^4.1.0",
"echarts-for-react": "^2.0.14",
"google-maps-react": "^2.0.2",
"immutability-helper": "^2.7.1",
"inputmask": "^4.0.2",
"jquery": "^3.3.1",
"lightbox2": "^2.10.0",
"lodash": "^4.17.11",
"moment": "^2.22.2",
"npm": "^6.4.1",
"query-string": "^6.2.0",
"rc-queue-anim": "^1.6.5",
"react": "^16.5.2",
"react-animated-css": "^1.0.4",
"react-bootstrap-sweetalert": "^4.4.1",
"react-calendar": "^2.17.3",
"react-chosen": "^0.3.8",
"react-dnd": "^7.4.5",
"react-dnd-html5-backend": "^7.4.4",
"react-dom": "^16.5.2",
"react-facebook-login": "^4.1.1",
"react-ga": "^2.5.6",
"react-geolocated": "^2.4.0",
"react-google-autocomplete": "^1.0.18",
"react-google-login": "^4.0.1",
"react-js-pagination": "^3.0.2",
"react-loadable": "^5.5.0",
"react-owl-carousel2": "^0.3.0",
"react-paginating": "^1.3.0-hook.1",
"react-redux": "^5.0.7",
"react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
"react-router-redux": "5.0.0-alpha.9",
"react-scripts": "2.0.0-next.3e165448",
"react-scroll-up-button": "^1.6.4",
"react-select": "^2.4.3",
"react-slick": "^0.24.0",
"react-tag-autocomplete": "^5.11.1",
"react-tag-input": "^6.4.0",
"react-tagsinput": "^3.19.0",
"reactstrap": "^6.4.0",
"redux": "^4.0.0",
"redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
"reqwest": "^2.0.5",
"sendbird": "^3.0.81",
"slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
"wowjs": "^1.1.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
"start": "react-app-rewired start",
"build": "react-app-rewired build",
"test": "react-app-rewired test --env=jsdom",
"eject": "react-scripts eject",
"prettier": "prettier --write ./src/**/**/**/*"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "development": [
  "last 2 chrome versions",
  "last 2 firefox versions",
  "last 2 edge versions"
],
    "production": [
  ">1%",
  "last 4 versions",
  "Firefox ESR",
  "not ie < 11"
]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
"babel-plugin-import": "^1.8.0",
"bootstrap": "^4.1.3",
"cdn-loader": "^0.1.8-0",
"history": "^4.7.2",
"html-webpack-cdn-plugin": "^0.2.0",
"html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
"loaders.css": "^0.1.2",
"node-sass": "^4.9.3",
"prettier": "^1.14.2",
"prop-types": "^15.6.2",
"react-app-rewire-less": "^2.1.2",
"react-app-rewired": "^1.5.2",
"redux-immutable-state-invariant": "^2.1.0"
  }
}
```

Any help or clue will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you are sure 100% that it doesn't work, this maybe worth a bug report in the relevant git repository. Did you try it on Node 10?

Comment: I have seen another developer log this issue but they closed it saying its a webpack configuration issue

Comment: Need to see your webpack config.

Comment: Actually, try React-Redux version greater than 5.1

Comment: I have upgraded to 7.x and it now gives the same error but insead of connectadvanced the error is in providers.js

Comment: ./node_modules/react-redux/es/components/Provider.js
Module not found: Can't resolve '@babel/runtime/helpers/esm/assertThisInitialized' in '/Users/apple/websites/frontend/node_modules/react-redux/es/components'

Comment: https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/issues/1159